# TTS HTML5 Audio EventListener

Tags: javascript, html, audio, addeventlistener

my Idea is to create a JS which dynamically playes any text as an audio file using the Google "TTS Api". Here is a part of my JS Code an the Error I get when executing the file in Chrome. Somehow i can't access to some Audio Objects in my Array in the for-Loop.

The Array `text_part` contains the text i want to use.
The Array `audioElementListe` contains the different audio-Objects.

The Error i get:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'play' of undefined

BTW english is not my native language and i'm a total JS-Beginner ;)

```
audioElementListe = new Array(3);
function start()
{
    text_part = new Array(3);
    text_part[0]='Hallo';
    text_part[1]='Florian';
    text_part[2]='Haha';

    for(var i = 0; i < text_part.length; i++)
    {   
        audioElementListe[i] = new Audio("");
    }

    for(var i = 0; i < text_part.length; i++)
    {   
            var help = 0;
            var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q="+text_part[i];
            audioElementListe[i] = new Audio("");
            document.body.appendChild(audioElementListe[i]);
            audioElementListe[i].src=url;
            audioElementListe[i].addEventListener('canPlay', function()                 
            {audioElementListe[i].play();}, false);

            //Error seems to be right here
            audioElementListe[i].addEventListener('ended', function()   
            {audioElementListe[i++].play();}, false);
    }
    audioElementListe[0].play();
}
```

EDIT: Made a "workaround" by not creating new Audio Objects but changing the source of it.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var audioElement;
var i;
function start()
{   
        i=0;
        text_part = new Array(3);
        text_part[0]='Hallo';
        text_part[1]='Florian';
        text_part[2]='Haha';

        var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q="+text_part[i];
        audioElement = new Audio("");
        document.body.appendChild(audioElement);
        audioElement.src=url;
        audioElement.addEventListener('canPlay', function() {audioElement.play();}, false);
        audioElement.addEventListener('ended', function()  
        {

                i++;
                if(i<text_part.length)
            {
                var url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=de&q="+text_part[i];
                audioElement.src=url;
                audioElement.addEventListener('canPlay', function() {audioElement.play();}, false);
                audioElement.play();
            }

;}, false);
        audioElement.play();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to break the string to be read in most parts of equivalent length and introduce a suitably js-statement setTimeOut(string, dt)

http://renatocappellani.altervista.org/blog/programmazione-dei-ritardi-in-javascript-settimeoutcomandotempo/